# Merging cells in openoffice deleting specific whitespace

Tags: openoffice-calc

Ok, so what I have is going to be 3 cells of data that I need to merge into a link to pictures in my store.  What I am looking for is an easy way to do this without double clicking and cntl v pasting for 4x at 100+ lines per page...

Cell 1.          Cell 2.           Cell 3

Assets/          name.         .jpg

Needs to be....    assets/name.jpg

This seems simple, but the problem is most of the names are 2 words and even the single word names when merged look like this......    assets/ name name .jpg
Giving me a space after/ and a space after the second name. If the "name" I am merging with has 2 or more parts I still need to keep those spaces intact or the link will not work the way it's set up currently.  I may need to rename the pictures into 1 solid word just for linking purposes, but hoping to avoid an extra step.
Is there a way to merge and remove the spaces I need gone to create the link? I have done a couple pages the hard way, not fun when I have 200+ pages to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Jerry

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me possible that an answer to a completely different Q may be of interest to you:

```
=TRIM(LOWER((A1))&TRIM(A2)&TRIM(A3))
```